# ContentPage update 1st StackLayout based on 2nd Selection

Tags: listview, c#-4.0, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have on contentPage (Xamarin Form) having two StackLayouts : StackLayoutA,StackLayoutB

StackLayoutA contains: ListView, BtnForStackLayoutB

StackLayoutB contains: Selection Criteria(Eg. 2 Buttons: BtnA,BtnB)

Both are added in Main ContentPage's StackLayout.

BtnForStackLayoutB is Button which makes StackLayoutB.IsvIsible=True/False;

Based on my click BtnA/BtnB i want to update ListView from StackLayoutA.
I am using following code which is updating listview's ItemSource but can not see on Page

lisview.ItemsSource = null;
lisview.BeginRefresh();
lisview.ItemsSource = _SelectionRuleList;
lisview.EndRefresh();

Am I missing any additional Settings?

Answer (score 0):

As per the description, I can see that you are making use of Xamarin.Forms
Apps developed using Xamarin.Forms can make use of ViewModels (MVVM).

Given the requirement, all I can think of is having a List in the MainViewModel and getting is Bonded with the ListView.

Now, when the BtnA/BtnB is clicked, the respective functions can actually update the List present in the MainViewModel thus updating the ListView.

I have created a sample showcasing the functionality:
https://github.com/anubhavranjan/ListViewTest

You can read more about Data Binding in [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/).